# Analyzing Multi-Platform Code with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I want to use SonarQube to perform a static analysis on a C++ application that is compiled for multiple platforms (Linux and Windows). Most of the code is the same, but it is possible that some code may be included or excluded with `ifdef/ifndef` depending on the platform being targeted.

Thus, my assumption is I would need to perform analysis when compiling for each platform. Is this a correct assumption? Or is SonarQube smart enough to find issues inside `ifdef/ifndef` blocks that were ignored by the complier?

If I need to perform an analysis on each platform, can I perform the analysis on each platform but have the results published to one SonarQube project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 questions here:

1) Do I need to perform 2 analyses? Assuming you're using SonarCFamily, the answer is "yes". SonarCFamily is part of the [Developer Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/developer/)($)

2) Can I perform the analysis on each platform but have 1 project? Yes and no. Each analysis will yield a separate project, but you can combine them into a meta project, called an Application. Applications are available as part of [Enterprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/)($). Enterprise edition includes all the features of developer edition.